# How to get Custom List in a Viewset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How can we write a function in a `ModelViewSet` that get a list of distinct record in the database?

Supposed that we have this model.

```
class Animal(models.Model):

    this_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    species_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ...
```

and serializer

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = (
            'this_id',
            'name', 
            'species_type', 
            ...,
        )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

and ViewSet.

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer
```

> I found this [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) useful such as decorators like `@list_route()`
>   but i can't understand it well.

**I would like to get list of distinct `Animal.species_type` record from the ViewSet. Please help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different options in filtering. You can send the species type via your request `/animals?species_type=MusMusculus` and reference it when you over ride the `get_queryset()` method in the view.

In your view

```
def get_queryset(self):
    species = self.request.query_params.get('species_type', None)
    if species is not None:
        queryset = Animals.objects.all().distinct('species_type')
        species = SpeciesSerializer(data=queryset)
    return queryset
```

Serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class Species(serializers.Serializer):
    species_type = serializers.Charfield()
```

alternatively, you can adopt a django filter framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

Comment: That is not what i mean sir, i would like to call  a function that get all distinct species_type record in my database via viewset. it means that i would not make a request with a particular species_type.

Comment: So that it means that we can define it in another serializer class? sounds great and i like the idea about the `url_path`.

Comment: it turns out you can't use the @detail route as that is only for single objects. i edited the answer and is kind of a combination of the two proposed.  you should have a whole new view for species type

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but what is the whole `url` to access this? while we can call an animal list with this url `/api/animal/` and animal's detail with this `/api/animal/<pk>`. What is the url for call get_queryset?

Comment: you see how you have the queryset = Animal.objects.all() get_queryset overrides that and is for your list endpoint so /api/animal/

Comment: i mean for the `species_type`, should the end point be `/api/species/` ?

Comment: that would be fine. don't forget to create another Viewset / serializer